# iphone: how can i find Image Information API?

Tags: iphone

I want to know Image Information API any information in iPhone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find image information from the following link..
[this](http://developer.iqengines.com/apidoc/current/)

```
   http://developer.iqengines.com/apidoc/current/
```